# Firestore CollectionReference with dynamic Path doesn't work

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to query a firestore collection with a dynamic path (user specific), it works hardcoded, but not dynamic with a variable, someone know the issue and can help?

Thanks in advance

```
final CollectionReference addressCollection =
 Firestore.instance.collection('users/r9qClctByGXinYAmB2MqQNctgd53/addresses');
```

works.

This not:

```
final CollectionReference addressCollection =
 Firestore.instance.collection('users/$userId/addresses');
```

userId is = r9qClctByGXinYAmB2MqQNctgd53

Full FirestoreDatabase code:

```
class FirestoreDatabase {
  final _service = FirestoreService.instance;

  static String userId;

  void setUserId(uid) {
    userId = uid; 
  }

  final CollectionReference addressCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection('users/$userId/addresses');

// Adresses List Stream

  Stream<List<Address>> get addressesStream {
    return addressCollection.snapshots().map(_addressListFromSnapshot);
  }

  List<Address> _addressListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return Address.fromMap(doc.data);
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

Comment: You want for a specific `r9qClctByGXinYAmB2MqQNctgd53` or for any id?

Comment: for a specific id

Comment: So you say that even if `$userId` holds the value of `r9qClctByGXinYAmB2MqQNctgd53` it is not recognized in your path?

Comment: it's recognized in the path ( i build also the whole path with a function and put this into the CollectionReference). i also get a snapshot but with an empty Map

Comment: Add a screenshot of database at that location.

Comment: hardcoded: I/flutter (20620): AsyncSnapshot<List<Address>>(ConnectionState.active, [Instance of 'Address', Instance of 'Address'], null)
I/flutter (20620): [Instance of 'Address', Instance of 'Address']

Comment: dynamic: I/flutter (20620): AsyncSnapshot<List<Address>>(ConnectionState.active, [], null)
I/flutter (20620): []

Comment: Screenshot: https://ibb.co/Tvd1f6S

Comment: fixed with this function:   CollectionReference getAdressessCollection(userId) {
    String path = 'users/$userId/addresses';
    final CollectionReference userAddressCollection =
        Firestore.instance.collection(path);
    return userAddressCollection;
  }

Comment: If you solved your own problem, then feel free to answer your own question as well.